# Does Highstocks.js covers Highchart.js's features?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to purchase licence for either of the library. Before that I want to know whether highstock covers all features of highcharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes All features in Highcharts.js are covered in highstock.js. There are some charts like Bubble, 3d bubble etc covered in highcharts-more.js these are not covered in highstock.js

Answer (score 1):

All features of Highcharts are included in Highstock